# Woocommerce update payment methods based on shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im doing some changes on my eshop, I have moved shipping method and payment method choices from `checkout` page to `cart` page, but now those tables have lost their auto-update functionality, and this leads to getting order errors, based on "invalid payment method". I know I need to move some action, method or anything as well to the cart page, I just cant figure out what I need to move there.

Code I have moved from `checkout` to `cart` for displaying shipping methods

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

functions.php action change

```
remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20);
add_action('order-checkout-methods', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20);
```

Code I have moved from `checkout` to `cart` for displaying payment methods

```
<?php do_action('order-checkout-methods'); ?>
```

Problem is not in the custom function. The auto-update worked well with this, but only when it was in `checkout`
Any idea, what i need to add to the `cart` to make it work?

Comment: Can you brief the use case? I mean why you were trying to move the Shipping methods & Payment methods from Checkout to the Cart page? That'd help me understand it better.

Comment: @VinayJain Well basically, Im doing it because I want the user to be able to see the final price in the cart already (price with shipping costs, payment method fees), and then in checkout only fill the adress and order. The orders are weight-based, and users might need to adjust the amount of items in cart based on cart weight, and if I keep the payment and shipping in checkout, they would need to jump back and forth in order to adjust the order to meet the criteria (lower weight = cheaper shipping)

Comment: There is some Javascript and AJAX code responsible for the auto update, you have to do a lot of work to make this work on cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have moved the display of **shipping methods** and **payment methods** from the **checkout page** to the **cart page**. but the issue is the **auto-update** functionality has been lost. that's why you need restore these.

To restore the **auto-update** functionality, you will need to move the relevant actions, methods, or code that handle the update of these fields to the **cart page**.

Comment: Understood, just by theory, what actions are responsible for this behaviour?